# Video downloader companion app not found on firefox. How to change it?

Tags: firefox, snap, extension

I installed the companion app for `videodownloaderhelper` a while ago but my firefox extension refuses its existence saying `no native app found`.
Perhaps it's having trouble locating it? It works fine in Chrome and Chrome is able to locate it.

Firefox is in `/home/snap` and Chrome is installed in `/opt`, along with the extension which is also in `/opt`

So is the issue that firefox is in the wrong location? Is there and issue with the companion app itself?
If so, how to I change Firefox's location? Any help or insight appreciated!

Comment: That companion app on Windows is spam-filled. I'l look for another video download extension.

Comment: Where are other extensions to Firefox installed when using the snap installation?  I have been digging around, but can't find it.  I suppose once we know where to put it, the companion app can simple be copied to that location, or what?

Comment: @LifeBoy they're installed to your user profile space, not to Firefox's installation directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 Video Download Helper can't (ever) find its Companion App](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411661/ubuntu-22-04-video-download-helper-cant-ever-find-its-companion-app)

Answer (score 1):

You can launch firefox out of snap sandbox with this command in the terminal: /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin

For more details see: [Ubuntu 22.04 Video Download Helper can't (ever) find its Companion App](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411661/ubuntu-22-04-video-download-helper-cant-ever-find-its-companion-app)

Comment: Very useful answer, and although it is a hack, it's a very useful one!