# ytdownloader (AKA Youtube Downloader) requires root password!

Tags: xubuntu, youtube, download-manager

I just installed Youtube Downloader on my laptop (Xubuntu 22.04). When I try to use it (from either the app menu or command line) the main window is displayed but I get a pop up message asking to authenticate as root. What should I do to use this app as an ordinary user?

Edit: For the installation I followed the instructions given in this thread [Ubuntu 22.04 Video Download Helper can't (ever) find its Companion App](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411661/ubuntu-22-04-video-download-helper-cant-ever-find-its-companion-app/1415304#1415304):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation the last week. I'll look into the issue. There should be no root access necessary, except when updating the yt-dl library.

Comment: Checking it on a current Ubuntu(Gnome) 22.04 I can't reproduce it. There is only one case when a dialog opens: pressing the cog icon to update the yt-dl library. The OP encounters a dialog on opening the application without any further interaction. What happens with: `python3 /opt/ytdownloader/YtGui.py`. What are your user rights? Enter: `id` in a terminal. At last I'd like to see how the software was installed. Please add the output of `ls -la /opt/ytdownloader/` also to your question

Comment: I just tested, python3 /opt/ytdownloader/YtGui.py works fine with no error message. I also tried YtGui from the app menu and command line, both too work fine! I did not use the laptop since I posted my question, thus may be re-booting was enough to fix the issue. Sorry for the unnecessary inconvenience.

Comment: apt method did not work for me.   https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader   "Preparing to unpack .../ytdownloader_1.4.4+1~jammy_all.deb ...
Unpacking ytdownloader (1.4.4+1~jammy) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ytdownloader_1.4.4+1~jammy_all.deb (--unpack):"

Comment: Video Downloader is best as a snap and it works just fine for me in both 22.04 and 23.04. Ask @kanehekill for comment. I'm sure he will be able to guide you. I've tried both the apt version and the snap and tbh, the snap is far better and offers more functionality.